# In person contactless credit card payments

Tags: payment-processor

Are there any payment processors that integrate with CiviCRM that have an in person contactless payment option?

I'm imagining a situation where we ask someone their name, bring up their contact, input an amount and then ask them to tap or insert their card to charge that amount to the card.

We are in Canada.

Comment: There was a presentation on using Stripe coupled with a card reader at the Manchester sprint last October - might be worth reaching out on Mattermost to start a chat with the team that were using it?